# This 'is' here is for what?

Tags: grammar

> It's as long as the Eiffel Tower is tall

I think sentence below is correct one

> It's as long as the Eiffel Tower tall

Answer (score 1):

The *is* is required because the formula *as X as* has to be followed by either a noun phrase (eg *as sober as a judge*) or by a finite clause (*as honest as the day is long*).

In your example "the Eiffel tower tall" is a noun phrase (*the Eiffel tower*) followed by an adjective (*tall*), which does not normally create any kind of sentence component.

You may be thinking of coordination or disjunction, where common components can sometimes be deleted from the second clause or phrase, eg

> I went home by bike and John by car

where the verb *went* does not need to be repeated. But *as X as* is not one the contexts that allow this.

Answer (score 0):

When we're speaking about somebody's hight or the height of a building, we usually use the adjective **tall** and not **long**. The reason is because the word **long** talks about how large something is in terms of its length. The word **tall**, on the other hand, describes how large something is in terms of its height. The two words are actually quite different and that's why your sentence sounds a little bit odd if you're comparing two buildings. This is my first point.

The second point is that although you definitely could say, **"It's as tall as the Eiffel Tower is tall."**, the **is tall** part is just redundant and no one would, generally, ever say it like that (notice that in this case you can't omit the second **is**). So, here's how it's normally said:

> It's as tall as the Eiffel Tower.

However, **"It's as long as the Eiffel Tower is tall."** is a normal English expression when you're comparing two things that are measured differently. You would never say it about two buildings, but you might say it when you want to compare one thing that is measure vertically with something else that is measured horizontally. So, basically you just want to say that each item is extreme in its own way even though they're not using the same measurement.

PS: You should always include the source of your examples or the context in which they're used. Otherwise, it leaves too much room for misinterpretation.